# How to get image from assets by folder ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I heve Assets catalog like this

- Assets

  - ComponentA - folder

    - Background - image
  - ComponentB - folder

    - Background - image

how i can get image depend of component (folder) ?
I like to use something what it is

```
let image = UIImage(named:"ComponentA/Background")
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get image depending on folder by "Providing Namespace" to folder.

1. Select folder in .xcassets
2. Check "Providing Namespace" in last tab (see attached image)
3. Access image using `var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"New Folder/bgimg")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**folders are for our reference only**

> you need to provide different names, and use only image names in programming.